# Powershell - what is wrong with my countdown timer

Tags: powershell

I have a script of counter that expects two parameters:

1) seconds to wait before the counter starts.

2) counter duration in seconds.

For example, if I input 3,10 
I would like that after 3 seconds the timer will countdown from 10 to 0 and write it to the output every second.

This is my script:

```
$timeBeforeStart = $args[0]
$waitSeconds = $args[1]  

$startTime = get-date
$endTime   = $startTime.addSeconds($waitSeconds)
$timeSpan = new-timespan $startTime $endTime
start-sleep -s $timeBeforeStart
while ($timeSpan -gt 0) 
{
    $timeSpan = new-timespan $(get-date) $endTime
    write-host $([string]::Format("`rTime Remaining: {0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}",
    $timeSpan.hours, $timeSpan.minutes, $timeSpan.seconds)) 
    sleep 1
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, the sleep seems to work simultaneity with the counter instead of delay the counter.

```
PS C:\> c:\555.ps1 3 10 
Time Remaining: 00:00:07
Time Remaining: 00:00:05
Time Remaining: 00:00:04
Time Remaining: 00:00:03
Time Remaining: 00:00:02
Time Remaining: 00:00:01
Time Remaining: 00:00:00
Time Remaining: 00:00:00
```

I've also tried **start-sleep -s** and the results where the same.

by the way, what is the difference between sleep and "start-sleep -s" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *what is the difference between sleep and "start-sleep -s"*?

No difference, `sleep` is just alias of `Start-Sleep`.

> *Unfortunately it doesn't work, the sleep seems to work simultaneity with the counter instead of delay the counter.*

You might want to put the sleep before the counter starts before getting the first `$timeSpan`:

```
start-sleep -s $timeBeforeStart

$startTime = get-date
$endTime   = $startTime.addSeconds($waitSeconds)
$timeSpan = new-timespan $startTime $endTime
while ($timeSpan -gt 0) 
{
 # ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
$timeBeforeStart = 0
$waitSeconds = 60

Start-Sleep -Seconds $timeBeforeStart

$waitSeconds..0 | Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host "`r          Time Remaining: $_ " -NoNewline -foregroundcolor green
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
$timeBeforeStart = 3
$waitSeconds = 10

Start-Sleep -Seconds $timeBeforeStart

$waitSeconds..0 | Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host "Time Remaining: $_"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}


Time Remaining: 10
Time Remaining: 9
Time Remaining: 8
Time Remaining: 7
Time Remaining: 6
Time Remaining: 5
Time Remaining: 4
Time Remaining: 3
Time Remaining: 2
Time Remaining: 1
Time Remaining: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This also does the same thing:

```
$timeBeforeStart = 3
$waitSeconds = 10

Start-Sleep -Seconds $timeBeforeStart
$endTime = (get-date).addSeconds($waitSeconds)

while ( (get-date) -lt $endTime )
    {
    Write-Host "Time Remaining: $("{0}" -f ([int](new-timespan $(get-date) $endTime).totalseconds))"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
```